# Can't get heroku procfile

Tags: python, heroku, chatbot

I'm trying to build up a deep-learning-based facebook chatbot (using Python). I'm trying to deploy it on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) firstly, but as I'm using the command `web: gunicorn echoserver:app` the terminal says `web: command not found`. Howevere, I've installed `gunicorn` already.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are typing `web:`, which is not a command line interface (CLI) command.

If you've installed `gunicorn`, then the *command* (from the CLI) is `gunicorn`.  Something like, for instance

```
gunicorn echoserver:app
```

---

I suppose it's also possible that you have a Windows machine.  `gunicorn` does not work on Windows, so you would need to use something like [`waitress`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/).  With `waitress`, you **would** type `web:` on a Windows machine, so that it would be something like

```
web: waitress-serve echoserver:app
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the procfile is literally a file you place in your repository. The contents of the procfile should contain the command you want Heroku to run to start your server.

So in the root directory of your repo, you should have a `Procfile` (named exactly that with no file extension) with the following contents:

```
web: gunicorn echoserver:app
```

The first part (`web:`) is just used to tell Heroku which dyno to run the second part (the command) on. So Heroku will only run the command on `web` dynos and not on background dynos.

More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile